# Callable returning a constant in python standard library

Tags: python

Is there, in any python standard library package, a callable that, given an arg, returns a callable which always returns said arg?

What I'm looking for is basically an equivalent `operator.itemgetter` for the following function:

```py
def constant_return(return_value): 
   return lambda *args, **kwargs: return_value
```

The main use-case I see right now would be to use it as the second argument of `unittest.mock.patch` when decorating a test case

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using `partial`:

```
from functools import partial
def constant_return(return_value):
    def constant_return_value(return_value):
            return return_value
    return partial(constant_return_value, return_value)
cr = constant_return(5)
cr()
# outputs 5
```

This will make constant_return return a partial function with the nested function and the return value you passed in. When called, the returned callable will return the value you initially passed in.

Or better yet, using lambda:

```
def constant_return(return_value):
    return partial(lambda x: x, return_value)

cr = constant_return(5)
cr()
# Outputs 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see the point of using `partial` here instead of directly returning the lambda?

Comment: @Lotram If you returned the lambda on its own, you'd have to pass the argument back to it every time. The partial returns a version of the lambda where it will be called with the `return_value` that you pass in to `constant_return()`. So all you need to do is call it without worrying about what the constant is you're passing is because that's already been set. Either that or I've completely misunderstood your question.